# Conditional Multifactor Authentication in a Azure AD B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

In the Azure AD B2C out-of-the-box flows, you can configure conditional MFA by checking a few radio buttons as so:
[image: Enabling MFA in a flow]

I'm trying to replicate the same thing in a custom policy but all of the documentation and samples I have found are either incomplete or convoluted. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I thought Azure AD B2C was going to make my life easier, but I've burned way too much time on it. I'm very close to abandoning the idea of using it at this point...

Comment: You've probably seen https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/conditional-access-user-flow?pivots=b2c-custom-policy and https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/conditional-access? If so, what specific issues are you having?

Comment: @rbrayb Thanks for the response. I ended up figuring this out yesterday and will post my solution once everything is buttoned up. I did come across and use both of the resources you linked to (as well as several others) to come up with the solution. I find the documentation kind of scattered, and so it took me a bit to make sense of everything and pull it together...

Answer (score 0):

•   You can try the following sample policy code given in the below link and enable all the conditional multi factor verification methods through the custom policy in your Azure AD B2C application. They will not be the same as the ‘Conditional Access’ policy options page where the conditional access MFA policy is to be configured: -

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples#multi-factor

From the above link, I have tried to implement the option of ‘Microsoft Authenticator App’ verification option as a second authentication verification option as below: -

[image: Github MFA page]
[image: B2C signup signin]

Thus, in this way, email address is verified during sign up process and when we proceed to sign in using this mail ID, the two-factor authentication enabled asks for Microsoft Authenticator verification code as below: -

[image: Signup process page]
[image: Email verification page]
[image: Authenticator app code]

And then we can get the successful token retrieval information as below: -

[image: Access token retrieval]